# Wildfly And c3p0 Hibernate Connection Pool Configuration

Tags: hibernate, wildfly, c3p0

our application runs on Wildfly 10.The datasource configuration standalone.xml is like this :-

```
   <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS">
        <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1</connection-url>
        <driver>h2</driver>
        <pool>
            <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
            <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
            <prefill>true</prefill>
        </pool>
        <security>
            <user-name>sa</user-name>
            <password>sa</password>
        </security>
    </datasource>
```

Which configures the min-pool-size, min-pool-size and prefill.

If we ALSO used c3p0 with Hibernate configuration, ie have the following in settings in the hibernate.cfg.xml

```
hibernate.c3p0.min_size=5
hibernate.c3p0.max_size=20
hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery=SELECT 1
hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout=true
```

I was wondering

- Is it possible to have database connection pool configuration in
  Wildfly and in our application ?
- How will the wildfly config and c3p0 config work togather ?
- Will the 2 configuration cause issues ?

Thank you for your help.
Pete

PS - We will beat the virus and all take care.